# MySQL - How to join same table multiple times to retrieve different values of the same field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have seen similar questions asked, but this is slightly different. I have not been able to get the desired result using the advice from previously asked questions. I apologize if this is unclear in any way. Please feel free to ask if you need any clarification...

I have a SOFTWARE table that displays each type and version of software that can be installed. There is a MACHINE table with a list of all the machines (not too important for this...). There is also a MACHINE_SOFTWARE table that lists only a MACHINE_ID and a SOFTWARE_ID. So the MACHINE_SOFTWARE table may show machine 1 with software 1, machine 1 with software 4, machine 1 with software 5, machine 2 with software 1, machine 2 with software 2, and so on...

I am writing a query that will show, for each machine, the software versions for four specific softwares.

So, for each MACHINE_ID, I need to see the SOFTWARE.VERSION field 4 times.

This is what I have that does not work properly:

```
SELECT MS.MACHINE_ID, A.VERSION AS A_VERSION, B.VERSION AS B_VERSION, C.VERSION AS C_VERSION, D.VERSION AS D_VERSION
FROM MACHINE_SOFTWARE MS
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE A ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = A.ID AND A.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftA%'
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE B ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = B.ID AND B.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftB%'
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE C ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = C.ID AND C.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftC%'
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE D ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = D.ID AND D.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftD%'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "*does not work properly*".

Comment: Some sample data and desired output often gets better response than text description of data.

Comment: Also, be careful about confusing issues of data retrieval with those of data display. The latter is often best handled in the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: The current query returns MACHINE #1 5 times... Once with all 4 software versions as NULL, another time with a correct value in A_VERSION (B_VERSION, C_VERSION, D_VERSION all still NULL), a third result with only B_VERSION not NULL, another with only C_VERSION, and the last with only D_VERSION. Ideally, the query would display a single MACHINE_ID followed by all four software versions in the same row. The same MACHINE_ID should not appear more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the matching is on multiple rows in `MACHINE_SOFTWARE`, a simple `GROUP BY` with appropriate aggregates seems in order;

```sql
SELECT MS.MACHINE_ID, 
       MAX(A.VERSION) AS A_VERSION, MAX(B.VERSION) AS B_VERSION,
       MAX(C.VERSION) AS C_VERSION, MAX(D.VERSION) AS D_VERSION
FROM MACHINE_SOFTWARE MS
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE A ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = A.ID AND A.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftA%'
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE B ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = B.ID AND B.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftB%'
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE C ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = C.ID AND C.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftC%'
LEFT JOIN SOFTWARE D ON MS.SOFTWARE_ID = D.ID AND D.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE 'SoftD%'
GROUP BY MS.MACHINE_ID
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70e7e/1).

Comment: This worked!! Thank you very much. I tried the GROUP BY earlier, but totally overlooked using MAX as well so that values would not be null.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your query  i have proceeded in the following way

first  i divide this 3 tables into 4 tables , apart  from machine table  i took 3 another table

1 **software** : Software_id[pk] ,software_name

2 **software_version** : version_id[ pk ] , Software_id [ in a fk relation with software ]

3 **machine_software** : version_id , MACHINE_ID .  [ version_id + MACHINE_ID is pk for this table]  and [ version_id has fk relation with software_version and MACHINE_ID has fk relation with MACHINE  table ]

Now to list  all available version of any software in any  machines  i  run the below query

```
SELECT ms.`version_id` , sv.`Software_id` , s.`software_name` , ms.`MACHINE_ID` , 
FROM  `machine_software` ms
INNER JOIN  `software_version` sv ON ms.version_id = sv.version_id
AND sv.Software_id = ( 
SELECT  `Software_id` 
FROM software_version
WHERE  `version_id` = ms.`version_id` ) 
INNER JOIN  `software` s ON sv.`Software_id` = s.`Software_id` 
AND s.`software_name` = ( 
SELECT  `software_name` 
FROM  `software` 
WHERE  `Software_id` = sv.Software_id ) 
ORDER BY  `version_id` ASC
```

I f you want you can add version name field also in the software_version  table , then in the query to  show the version name you have to add that field accordingly.